# What is the longest possible correct sequence of punctuation marks?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

How many logical, nonrepeating punctuation marks can be used in a row, in a sentence, while remaining grammatically correct?

For example,

> Julie said, "Bruno said, 'she went home (on South Beach Rd.,)' "; although, in reality, she went to work.

Comment: A better answer then the existing would, provide an answer that is not dependent on infinitely the same symbol.

Comment: Just a comment that many punctuation symbols are a matter of style, not grammar, such as the period you use after "Rd", and both period followed by comma in "eg.," and "ie.,"

Comment: I think this is off-topic here.  It is more of a "puzzle" than a question about English.  I wonder if this would fit in https://puzzling.stackexchange.com

Comment: For quotes within quotes you can end with a sequence alternating ’ and ” as long as you like.

Comment: Punctuation can never be grammatically correct nor incorrect. Punctuation is about writing, not about grammar. The same words spoken in the same order always have the same grammar. You haven't said whether you mean without letters between them, or on the same page, etc. Do emoji count? What do you consider punctuation? And really, this belongs on some puzzle site not here.

Comment: Julie said, "Bruno said, 'she went home (on South Beach Rd.)!' "; and then said  she went to work, didn't she?

Comment: @GEdgar https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92392/what-is-the-longest-possible-correct-sequence-of-punctuation-marks

Comment: @Lambie I am not sure if the exclamation mark is correct?

Comment: Whoops! Again: Julie said, "Bruno said 'she went home - on South Beach Rd!' "; and then said she went to work, didn't she? A dash is better because quotes don't really work with spoken languages. Dashes indicate a pause. You could put quotes at the beginning: (for the record) and it would indicate a transcript or that spoken language is being written down.

Comment: This is better suited to https://puzzles.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mitch... Is it a new puzzle to figure out the actual link?

Comment: @GEdgar haha [it's a puzzle innit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Xaddell, it is not entirely clear what role the newly inserted word *logical* is supposed to play in making the question more focused. Does it add anything to 'remaining grammatically correct'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nested quotes can go on forever. So you can, in theory, have a countable infinity of contiguous punctuation symbols.

Comment: This is simply not discursively possible. It would be gibberish.

Comment: It would be within the spirit of ELU to delete this vastly over-upvoted answer to a question so clearly, as it stands, trivial. It's not even a valid answer ('How many **changing** punctuation marks can be used in a row, in a sentence ...); the whole does little for site integrity.

Comment: Happy new year to you, too, @Edwin :) . Nested quotes are usually alternating single- and double- quotes, satisfying the *changing* aspect. Feel free to vote to delete, though I think it answers the question.

Comment: The question has happily been closed, and it's reassuring that GEdgar and Mitch would like myself be happier to see it over on _Puzzling_. Nevertheless, Happy New Year to yourself, and a slimmer and healthier ELU.